# Running Python scripts in Slurm

Tags: python, slurm, hpc

I've recently started a new job and need to run some scripts on the HPC through Slurm.

My scripts are written in Python, and therefore I want to execute these using `python script.py` in my `.slurm` file.

However, when I try to run the `.slurm` file, it doesn't seem to be able to call the python scripts. I've tried loading the python environment using `module load anaconda3`, and variations thereof (e.g. `module load python`, etc.). Attached is my `array.slurm` file, for reference[(.slurm file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPEPr.png). I've left the account and mail-user empty for uploading here for anonymity, but I have these in when I run the script.

The error file output by Slurm indicates the following:

```
/var/spool/slurmd/job220829/slurm_script: line 19: module: command not found
```

Can someone offer practical guidance? I need to run these Python scripts as soon as possible.

Comment: Every HPC system is different. Have you got any documentation?

Comment: There's no documentation. I only have documentation for Slurm. I found this (https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compute/modules.html), but for some reason I don't seem to have a "module" command, given the error I received. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3):

As [md2perpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412534/md2perpe) mentioned every HPC system is different. They customize the slurm scheduler up to some extent. Still many HPCs share the same basic commands.

For instance, here is a job submission script that I created to run a python file on a GPU node.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --time=00:00:40
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --job-name=gpu_check
#SBATCH --output=gpu.%j.out
#SBATCH --error=gpu.%j.err
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --account=scw1901
#SBATCH --partition=accel_ai

module load anaconda/3
source activate base
python gpu.py
```

I can suggest you the following:

- After loading anaconda module you should activate the conda virtual environment. For example, `source activate base`. To see a list of available conda environments type this `conda env list`. Then activate the conda environment of your choice.
- I don't know what your python script is, so can't really comment on the argument that you used.
- Make sure you have access to the partition. To see a list of partition type `sinfo`. Also check the state. If it is `drain` or `reserved` then you simply can't use that partition.
- Maybe you can run your script without `--ntasks-per-nodes` and `--array`. Why not try my job script?
- If nothing works, please paste the output of error file in your question. In my case, the `JOBID` is defined by `%J` not `%a` as in your case.
- You can remove those email arguments `--mail` if you don't need it.
- What is `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`? If you don't know please remove it.
- You said you don't have `module` command. The error is in line 19. But you used module command in line 18. Are you sure you are sharing the correct job script?
- Can you run `module load anaconda/3` in the login node? Just copy and paste this after SSHing. If yes then `module` is available.

Comment: What should be extension of this kind of file @Prakhar Sharma? It is should be .sbatch or .sh.  I tried running with .sh extension like sbatch testing.sh, but I am not getting email.

Comment: Linux systems don't need extensions. You can rename your job script to `array.jpeg` and it will still work with `sbatch array.jpeg`. For email you may need to check if emailing has been implemented on your HPC cluster.

Comment: Thank you @Prakhar Sharma. Yes, your email part also works. Today I am getting emails also. Yesterday,  there must be some problem with the cluster.